# why code is printing all the first index?

Tags: c++, string, file

Im trying to write a program that converts word from a text file into pig Latin. i got the code that  sepratare the words for the text file but i am now havign trouble with trying to sort them out. when i run this code it always prints first index of all of the words not  the ones that matches the if statement

```
void wordpro(string sent)
{
  string word;

  istringstream iss(sent, istringstream::in);
  while (iss>> word)
  if (word[0] == 'a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'||'A'||'E'||'I'||'O'||'U')
  {
    cout<< word[0] <<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
if (word[0] == 'a'||'e'||'i'||'o'||'u'||'A'||'E'||'I'||'O'||'U')
```

This is not how `||` works in C++. But that does **not** mean that the above will result in compilation error. No, that is correct from compiler point of view; the only problem with it is that it doesn't do what you *intend* it to do! Instead, the condition will always be `true`. That is why it prints first character of all the words in your code.

To get what you intend, you have to write `||` as:

```
if (word[0] == 'a'|| word[0] == 'e'|| word[0] ==  'i' || ... so on)
```

That is, you have to compare every character separately. That is surely irritating.

---

C++11 has come to save you from this, so you can use [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) as:

```
//C++11 only

std::string const v = "aeiouAEIOU";
if (std::any_of(v.begin(), v.end(), [](char c){ return word[0] == c;})
```

---

Or you can use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) as:

```
//C++03 and C++11 both

if ( std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), word[0]) != v.end() )
```

which got a bit shorter than the previous one. Moreover, this will work in C++03 also!

---

Or you can use [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) as:

```
//C++03 and C++11 both

if ( std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), word[0]) )
```

which is even shorter.

---

Or you can use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) as:

```
//C++03 and C++11 both

if ( v.find(word[0]) != std::string::npos)
```

which is shortest!

---

Read the docs to understand what each of them really do, and why it would work for your case:

- [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)
- [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)
- [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)
- [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Hope that helps.

Comment: is there a shorter way to do that?

Comment: or `v.find(word[0])!=std::string::npos` if you make use of the monolithic design of string.

Answer (score 0):

Above suggestion of using lots of `word[0] == 'a' || word[0] == 'e' || ...` is correct solution to "fix" what you have written in the way that it would do what you expect from a single if-statement.

You could do this:

```
 switch(word[0])
 {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    ... /// you'll have to fill the rest in yourself. 
        cout << word[0]; 
        break; 
 }
```

or you could use the old-fashioned C style `strchr`:

```
if (strchr("aeiouAEIOU", word[0]) != NULL)
{
    cout << word[0];
}
```

There are probably half a dozen other solutions as well. It all depends on what "style" you prefer. I'd probably go for the switch as my first choice.