# there is an error shows up to be "comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'const char *')"

Tags: c, pointers

```
char * piglatin(const char s[], int len) {
    char * result[len+3] = s[];
    char * current[len+3] = s[];
    if(s[0]=="o"||"u"||"e"||"a"||"i"){
        result[len-1] = "y";
        result[len-2] = "a";
        result[len-3] = "-";
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i<len-1; i++){
            result[i] = current[i+1];
            result[len-1] = "-";
            result[len] = current[0];
            result[len+1] = "a";
            result[len+2] = "y";
        }
    }


    }
```

I met a problem when I was doing program homework for my computer science class. the professor want us to append "-ay" after the string s if the first letter of s is vowel, otherwise remove the first letter of s and append "-?ay". My error appears at the "if(s[o]=="o"||"u"||"e"||"a"||"i")" and it said "comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'const char *')". I feel confused since s is not a pointer and the right hand side is not integer either.

Comment: You must place s[0] == after each or in your if - and use single quotes ('), not double quotes (") for your constants.

Comment: This simply isn’t valid C++. You need to disable compiler extensions (GCC does that via `-std=c++11`) and enable warnings and pedantic parsing.

Comment: Changed tag to 'c' as this is not a C++ type of thingy going on here...

Comment: What is this: `char * current[len+3] = s[];` supposed to mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [why code is printing all the first index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548814/why-code-is-printing-all-the-first-index)

Answer (score 2):

cmon brother ... use 'o' not "o" for all others to and in if statement you have to compare them all to s[0] like this s[0]=='o'||s[0]=='u'||s[0]=='e'||s[0]=='a' and so on . but you will still get errors so dont forget to return a value of pointer :) and (const char s[]) s is constant how will you change it !!!!!! remove const

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. The compiler is complaining because `s[0]` is a `char` and `"o"` (and others) are pointers to char arrays (basically). To fix this, replace `"o"` with `'o'`.

There's a bigger issue though: you are only comparing s[0] to 'o'. The other things in your test will all evaluate to true:

```
    if(s[0]=='o'||s[0]=='u'||s[0]=='e'||s[0]=='a'||s[0]=='i'){
```

Comment: and fixed to start.  I'm sure there are other things in the above awating to be found though...

Comment: Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: NP - I took away my down vote as well.  I still don't like all the array -1 junk going on above.  Tastes real bad.  Probably another array overwrite in there somewhere.  Too tired to look for it though :)

Comment: Ah, I'll bet dollars to donuts that the second for loop is overwriting the string '\0' terminator with the +1/+2 stuff and causing bad.  This needs a rewrite to either use strings, vectors, or more care...

Answer (score 0):

In the below, `s[0]` is a char - so a form of integer, where `"o"` is a string -  `const char *` - so you are comparing a letter 'a'(or such) to the address of the string `"o".

```
if(s[0]=="o"||"u"||"e"||"a"||"i"){
```

You should do:

```
if(s[0]=='o' ... )
```

However, the || 'u' doesn't mean what I think you think it means. Since none of the characters (or strings in your code) are zero/NULL, they become `true`, and your if-statement will always be true.

You need to have a comparison statement:

```
if(s[0] == 'o'|| s[0] == 'u' ... )
```